# MediaPlayer URI

Tags: java, android, file, android-mediaplayer

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Music/";
    File directory = new File(path);
    File[] mSongsList = directory.listFiles();

    Uri mUri= Uri.fromFile(mSongsList[0]);
    Log.v("MainActivity",mUri.toString());
    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, mUri);
    mMediaPlayer.prepare();
    mMediaPlayer.start();
```

I am trying to play the first song in my list but,
i am getting an error on setDataSource.

**it say** "*Unhandled Exception: java.io.IOException*"

Comment: Plz add Your manifest code as well.? have you enabled read data from external storage permission.?

Comment: i think you have to check your URI is proper or not ? and also pass path Uri.parse(your_local_uri_path)

Answer (score 2):

Place music files(s) under res/raw or any other folder under SD card. We are going to refer the audio file based on the Uri.

Create MediaPlayer object:

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
```

Locate the audio file:

```
Uri myUri1 = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/Songs/ARR Hits/hosannatamil.mp3");
```

Set the audio stream type of the media player:

```
mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

Set the data source as a content Uri:

```
try {
    mPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri1);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI 
    correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (SecurityException e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI 
    correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI 
    correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Prepare the player for playback, synchronously:

```
try {
    mPlayer.prepare();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI 
    correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI 
    correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Start the player:

```
mPlayer.start();
```

The above information has been taken from the below link:

"https://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-mediaplayer-example-play-from-uri/"

Answer (score 0):

Keep your code inside the `try-catch` block.

```
try{
// your code
}catch(IOException exception){

}
```

This is because you are trying to get the `music file`. If its not present then it will throw `IOException`, so you must handle this.

Comment: the app i still crashing

Comment: But the file does exist in my device

Comment: what is the crash log?

Comment: i have posted the crash Log

Comment: Bro, i used this mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(mSongsList[1].toString()));
        mMediaPlayer.start();
and it was working

Comment: Anyways Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Replace Your Code Like below:

**Note: Make Sure That You Have Some Music In MusicDirectory.**

```
    String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).getAbsolutePath();
                File directory = new File(path);
try{
 File[] mSongsList = directory.listFiles();

                Uri mUri= Uri.fromFile(mSongsList[0]);
                Log.v("MainActivity",mUri.toString());
                mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, mUri);
                mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                mMediaPlayer.start();
}catch(IOException exception){
    e.printStacktrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you have read permissions in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

If you are using the android version Marshmallow or above you need to ask the user for `Runtime Permissions`.

[This](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-working-marshmallow-m-runtime-permissions/) is a good article to request runtime permissions.

For now you can go to the app info page and give the permissions manually. It will start working.

As in the image below :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can play the song from your device by the following codes, but I don't know how to play next songs and previous songs , if you have any idea , pls share me.

```
fun getURI(){
    val path: String =
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).getAbsolutePath()
    val directory = File(path)

    try {
         mSongsList= directory.listFiles()
        val mUri = Uri.fromFile((mSongsList as Array<File>?)!![0])
        Log.v("MainActivity", mUri.toString())

        mp!!.reset()
        mp!!.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
        mp!!.setDataSource(this, mUri)
        mp!!.prepare()
        mp!!.start()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```